# Why CMake attempts to compile my trashed file?

Tags: cmake

I added, as error protection, the lines

```
if ( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds not allowed." )
endif()
```

in front of my real stuff. For testing purposes, I `cd ..` and `cmake .` The protection works OK, those lines prevent in-source builds, and print the error message I expect. After that, I `cd build` and `cmake ..`. Now I receive the same error message. Even, if I `cd ..;rmdir build;mkdir build;cd build;cmake ..`. I noticed, that, despite the protection, the CMake generated files were written in my source directory. If I remove manually all those files, comment out the protection line, CMake want to put its files in the source, rather that in its build subdirectory.

In the console, I receive message

```
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/build_3686731566269/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/me/DEVEL/cpp/sandbox/myprog/build where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/me/.local/share/Trash/files" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

which is correct, but I do not want to compile from Trash, and not the deleted files. I removed the old work directory, crated a new one, copied the source files to the new directory, rebooted. The error keeps standing. In addition, if I use the same CMakeLists file from Kdevelop, it works fine.

Finally I emptied Trash, recreated build, and now everytring works fine again.
What is going on here?

Comment: have you checked if there were any hidden files? maybe you have somehow still been in the trash directory? not sure how trash works and how the terminal behaves when you move the folder to trash while your terminal is still in.  Though CMake will always generate files. You cannot completely protect yourself against an in-source build (it generates at least the CMakeCache.txt). Does the same happen if you use remove the files directly instead of moving them to trash somehow?

Comment: @Hayt I think the primary error is that CMake somehow, despite of the FATAL_ERROR protection (I receive the message) writes its files, which used to go in subdirectory build/, in my source directory. After I notice, I really remove them, which actually go into Trash. The rest of the issues is the consequence of the first one. My guess was that CMake only caches info in my work directory.

Comment: You cannot protect it from writing files. Some cmake files will always be written. It will produce maybe an error but you cannot protect it from writing it's own internal files first.

Comment: Maybe you moved the build directory to your trash, but the bash did not know about. It performs at the same location unless you make `cd <whatever>`.

Comment: I suggest in anycase you quote your string for comparison, namely: `if ( "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")` (Might help if you have some strange characters in your path)